# command is not defined, fresh installation

Tags: errors, texshop

I want to learn LaTeX and so I downloaded MacTeX, as I read that this would be the nicest solution for a Mac I am using.
Well, I opened TeXShop and inserted following source code:

```
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

But when I click to "typeset" I get following error:

> "test.tex: LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalize is not
>   defined: there is probably something wrong with the class file.

Do you know what to do here?
Thank you =)and sry for new be questions ;)
Dary

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If this is really all, you have inserted, then it will not work. You need some documentclass here. Please check and let us see a complete minimal example, which does not work for you.

Comment: As LaRiFaRi stated: Add a `\documentclass{article}` at the top of your document and it should work. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a missing \documentclass declaration

Answer (score 6):

With `\documentclass{article}` it works for me. 
Had that string in there before but probably I had a typo in there so it did not work.